# skip column count css attribute for li

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a multi column drop-down where first line is the heading saying "Select the options" it should be whole column. From second line It has to be considered column-count. The reason I am asking this specific layout is there is another functionality associated with it.

I am checking if there is an easy way to solve this by CSS?

Problem:

Can we ignore first li exclude from column count? Basically, first li is the heading saying "Select the options". I wanted it to be

```
<ul style="column-count: 2;">
<li style="color: gray;" class="label-default">Select the options</li>
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
<li>option4</li>
<li>option5</li>
<li>option6</li>
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
<li>option4</li>
<li>option5</li>
<li>option6</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using a `<ul>` and not a `<select>`?

Comment: It's dynamically built drop-down based on jQuery gentleSelect plug in. We integrated it with a CMS to show content based on the option selected

Comment: Ah, ok. Another dropdown plugin I like is https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. Just be aware that these type of plugins are typically not very accessible https://vimeo.com/84970341#t=614s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` on the first `li` and set a padding on the `ul` pushing the columns down.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  column-count: 2;
}
ul li.label-default {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="label-default">Select the options</li>
  <li>option1</li>
  <li>option2</li>
  <li>option3</li>
  <li>option4</li>
  <li>option5</li>
  <li>option6</li>
  <li>option1</li>
  <li>option2</li>
  <li>option3</li>
  <li>option4</li>
  <li>option5</li>
  <li>option6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: about to answer similar thing http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vmpxaa , seemed so obvious

Comment: @GCyrillus Yeah, it is ... but now, when I think about it, I personally would go with _Geeky's_ suggestion. It will flow better, as if the first `li` has a looooong text, one will get issues on narrower screens if a line break is needed.

Comment: Thanks @LGSon and GCyrillus. It helped. This fit's my requirement. I have an another functionality to reset the drop-down. It's already there so, don't want to change li to span.

Comment: @LGSon Now I have an issue, If the li.label-default has text more than two lines 1st and other li overlap. Do you suggest anything?

Comment: @vssrnr You can either use `column-span` [(fiddle demo 1)](https://jsfiddle.net/orv8Lkt0/) or move it outside [(fiddle demo 2)](https://jsfiddle.net/orv8Lkt0/1/) ... both as suggested by the other given answers, and moving it outside will have the best browser support since `column-span` appears to still not work in Firefox

Answer (score 4):

Can you apply `column-span: all;` to the first child? Seems like the simplest solution.

See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-span/

Answer (score 1):

you can hide it /you can make it a separate element instead of making it as li

check this snippet

```html
<span style="color: gray;" class="label-default">Select the options</span>

<ul style="column-count: 2;">

<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
<li>option4</li>
<li>option5</li>
<li>option6</li>
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
<li>option4</li>
<li>option5</li>
<li>option6</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I believe all `<label>` tags must be associated with a form element using the `for` attribute.

Comment: I suggest, for the reason _Ted_ pointed out, to use a `div` or a `span` instead of the `label` ... still, +1 from me as it will flow better than an absolute positioned `li` (as I posted in my answer)

Comment: yaa i agree ...changed it span